# How to pass parameter to regex in select statement using IBATIS

Tags: java, sql, oracle, mybatis, ibatis

How should I pass a parameter (user entered value) to regex using ibatis?

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE regexp_like(employeename, '^#employeeName#_[a-z][A-Z]$')`

The above statement doesn't work. Tried concatenation and still didn't work. Database is Oracle.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try: #{employeeName} ?

Comment: @RobertoNavarro:Not yet. I will try that and see if that works. But, the employeeName should be passed in between the # sign like this #employeeName#... right?